# React: setting up firebase auth with firebase-ui

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#demo) to setup firebase auth using firebase ui.

I added the firebase ui module using yarn. I have a firebase folder in my root directory in my react app. In it, I have a firebase.js file with:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'

const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET, 
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const database = firebase.database();

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
```

When I try to check that I am correct to this point, I get a console error that says:

```
firebaseApp.js:339 Uncaught FirebaseError {code: "app/duplicate-service", message: "Firebase: Firebase service named 'auth' already registered (app/duplicate-service).", name: "auth", stack: "auth: Firebase: Firebase service named 'auth' alre…t
```

I don't call firebase anywhere else in the app, so I think the only way this can be an error is if firebaseui already imports firebase. I tried removing the first import statement, but that then gives an error saying that firebase is not defined.

Does anyone know how to get the setup right?  I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034691/react-nextjs-firebase-error-refresh-firebase-app-named-default-already-exist). I can see the differences in approach. I have tried using the config statement used in the question. I still get the same problem.

Since posting this question, I hired someone on upwork to set this up for me. Despite spending USD400, I still have this issue. Other questions have posted this problem and identified a duplication in angular flare. I don't use angular.

The upwork contractor setup is as follows:

```
const config = {
  apiKey: settings.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: settings.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: settings.FIREBASE_DB_URL,
  projectId: settings.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: settings.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: settings.FIREBASE_MESSAGE_ID,
}

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

const database = firebase.database();
const auth = firebase.auth()

export {firebase, auth, database };
```

There is an extra const in this block for firebase.auth. I tried removing it but it doesn't make any difference. The console error still appears.

The SO question I linked above shows import statements importing from the library. All my import statements import my firebase.js file, which itself imports firebase. I wonder if that's the duplication? However, the import has the if statement in it, so I can't understand why that could be the problem. I do import FirebaseUI in my components, but I can't figure out if that is somehow importing firebase in duplication.

I'm looking for a solution with react. Does anyone know ho to configure firebase for use with a react app?

Comment: Looking at firebaseui demo, I see that firebaseui is imported only after the firebase has initialised. However, in your approach `firebase` and `firebaseui` are imported first, and then it gets initialised. 

refer: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/demo/public/index.html

Answer (score 21):

EDIT 2021: There is an official React component now - see saurabh's answer below.

I'm not sure what's going on with your error but I created a React app with `create-react-app` and got it working right away.

First I created 'firebase.js':

```
import firebaseui from 'firebaseui'

const config = ({
  // your config
})

// This is our firebaseui configuration object
const uiConfig = ({
  signInSuccessUrl: '/',
  signInOptions: [
    window.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
  ],
  tosUrl: '/terms-of-service' // This doesn't exist yet
})

// This must run before any other firebase functions
window.firebase.initializeApp(config)

// This sets up firebaseui
const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(window.firebase.auth())

// This adds firebaseui to the page
// It does everything else on its own
const startFirebaseUI = function (elementId) {
  ui.start(elementId, uiConfig)
}

export startFirebaseUI
```

Then edited existing App.js into this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { startFirebaseUI } from './firebase.js'

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    startFirebaseUI ('#firebaseui')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="firebaseui"></div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Firebaseui will create users for you, you don't need to do that manually. It will also throw a nasty error if it can't find the element so make sure
you don't ever call it without the element on the page!

If you need to run a function on login or logout, you can hook into `firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged`:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  // if user isn't null then we logged in
  if (user) {
    // login
  } else {
    // logout
  }
})
```

I suspected that your error had something to do with `firebaseui` interfering with `firebase.auth()` but try as I might I can't reproduce it.

Comment: anyone getting error on {import firebaseui from 'firebaseui'} can replace it with {import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'}
Well executed @Matt O'Tousa

Comment: did you add firebaseui.css in the index.html of project?
For me the styling didnt work till I add that.. the Google logo was giant and had to add css for applying styles.

Answer (score 8):

For all the users reaching here for integrating Firebase-UI in react application, I strongly recommend official node module.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebaseui

It is very well captured in npm. To explain in short:

1. Assuming you already have firebase in your project, install react-firebaseui via command: $ npm install --save react-firebaseui

   ```
    const uiConfig = {
    // Popup signin flow rather than redirect flow.
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    // Redirect to /signedIn after sign in is successful. Alternatively you can 
    provide a callbacks.signInSuccess function.
    signInSuccessUrl: '/signedIn',
    // We will display Google and Facebook as auth providers.
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ]
    };
   ```

Then add below tag in your render/return of the componant:

```
<StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
```

Comment: definitely the modern way this should be achieved!

Comment: Not compatible to React 18 anymore.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this issue as well most likely due to the recent issue with npm not working with the most up to date version of firebase on windows.

The issue is the file in node_modules/firebasui/dist/ npm.js has this as its first line.

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app'); require('firebase/auth');
```

I replaced that with:

```
var firebase=window.firebase;
```

I think imported firebase first and explicitly put in the window object and then imported firebaseui:

`var firebase = require('firebase');
window.firebase = firebase;
var firebaseui = require('firebaseui');`