# Firebase Modular SDK V9.0.0+ TypeError: Cannot read property 'apps' of undefined firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I got this error when trying to run my next.js app. I try lots of ways but I can't solve this. I am using firebase 9.0.1

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apps' of undefined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
.next\server\pages\_app.js (14:13) @ Object../firebase.js

  12 | };
  13 |
> 14 | const app = !firebase.apps.length
     |             ^
  15 |   ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  16 |   : firebase.app();
```

Here is my firebase.js

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

const app = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = app.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

Comment: Which version of Firebase are you using ? Also can you share complete code? I cannot see where Firebase is imported. If you are on v9, then use `getApps().length`

Comment: I am using firebase 9.0.1

Comment: Can you update your code with the imports? I'd like to confirm if you are using compat libraries or no.

Comment: import firebase from "firebase/app"; this is my import

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you are using the new Modular SDK `v9.0.1` which does not use `firebase.` namespace, you should use `getApps()` instead of `firebase.apps`.

```js
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {...}

if (!getApps().length) {
  //....
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = getFirestore(app)
const auth = getAuth(app)

export {db, auth}
```

However, you don't need to check if Firebase is already initialized in this new SDK. You can learn more about the new syntax in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

Also check: [Getting started with Firebase for web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQvOAnNvcNQ)

Comment: Thanks, was trying to follow https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react example and had to update it to this suggestion

Answer (score 2):

`if(!firebase)` is giving error due to new updates. Now code look like this

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();

export { addDoc, db, collection };
```

I suggest you to re-read firebase docs, they are very updated and many video tutorials codes are not working.
links : `https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup`
`https://firebase.google.com/docs/build`

Comment: NOTE: the codes will perfectly work in old projects, because they are made with previous versions of firebase. firebase will only give error in new projects made with new versions of firebase.